# how to repeat the matrix in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to rewrite the following python code in tensorflow, keras. However, I cannot find the np.matlib.repmat equivalent in tensorflow keras. Could anyone help me out with this issue?

```
index = np.arange(0,256);
index_transpose = index.reshape(256,1)

I = numpy.matlib.repmat(index_transpose,1,256).reshape(256,256);
J = numpy.matlib.repmat(index,256,1);
```

I and J should be in the shape: 
I shape: (256, 256), J shape: (256, 256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
index = K.arange(256) #[0,1,2...,255]

I = K.stack([index]*256, axis=-1) 
J = K.stack([index]*256, axis= 0)
```

Where:

```
I = [0,0,0....]
    [1,1,1,....]
    ...
    [255,.....]

J = [0,1,2,3...,255]
    [0,1,2,3...,255]
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
I = tf.tile(tf.reshape(index), [-1, 1]), [1, len(index)])
# [[0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1]
#  [2 2 2 2 2]
#  [3 3 3 3 3]
#  [4 4 4 4 4]]
J = tf.transpose(I)
# [[0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 3 4]]
```

assuming that `index = np.arange(0,5)` for testing purposes.